# Using Java8 lambda for argument matching on mocked class

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda, mockito

The class I'm unit testing takes a dependency and calls a function on that dependency. That function takes a complex object as its argument and produces a result. Now, I would like to mock the dependency and have it return something based on the argument passed in. A simplified, working version is given below.

Can I use Java 8 lambda expressions in the `when` method to eliminate the `ArgHasNext` class? Something like the commented code below (which does not compile).

```
class ArgHasNext implements ArgumentMatcher<Arg> {
    public boolean matches(Arg arg) {
        return arg.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object o) {
        return matches((Arg)o);
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ArgumentMatcherTest {

    @Mock
    private Dependency dep = mock(Dependency.class);

    @Test
    public void test() {

        when(dep.func(argThat(new ArgHasNext()))).thenReturn(true);
        // when(dep.func(argThat((Arg a) -> a.hasNext()))).thenReturn(true);
        // when(dep.func(argThat((Arg a) -> !a.hasNext()))).thenReturn(false);
        Sut sut = new Sut(dep);
        assertEquals(sut.method(new Arg(true)), "True");
        assertEquals(sut.method(new Arg(false)), "False");
    }
}

class Arg {
    private boolean hasNext;

    public Arg(boolean hasNext) {
        this.hasNext = hasNext;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.hasNext;
    }
}

class Sut {
    private Dependency dep;

    public Sut(Dependency dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    public String method(Arg arg) {

        if (dep.func(arg)) {
            return "True";
        }
        else {
            return "False";
        }
    }

}

class Dependency {
    public boolean func(Arg arg) {
        if (arg.hasNext()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm using Mockito-core version 2.0.54-beta.

**EDIT**
Okay, maybe I over-simplified the example. In the real case, the dependency `func` method returns paged query results that are processed in `SUT` before the tested method returns. Depending on `Arg`, I want the dependency `func` to return page 1 results the first time it's called and page 2 results the second time. I can only do this when I can have the mock return different values based on an argument passed to the function call. It this possible using lambdas in Mockito?

Comment: Just wondering: why are you using a 2.0 beta version that is years old? And maybe: can you give an example how you envision using lambdas here?

Comment: @GhostCat Look at the two commented lines in the test method. I think those two lines are much more expressive (if they would work). The ArgumentMatcher derived class works, but is not obvious.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I think you are investing your time in the wrong place. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, I would like to mock the dependency and have it return something based on the argument passed in.

You should not do that in the first place.
By any chance let your mocks return well defined constant values.

The reason is that you should keep your test code as simple as possible to reduce the risk of having your tests failing because the test code is wrong.

---

The solution to your problem might be mockitos `Answer` interface:

```
doAnswer(new Answer<YourReturnType>(){ 
    public YourReturnType answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
       YourParameterType parameter = (YourParameterType)invocation.getArguments()[0];
       // calculate your return value
       return yourCalculatedReturnValue;
    }
}).when(yourMock).theMethod(any(YourParameterType.class));
```

---

> To be clear, my mock is returning a constant value. The mock is called multiple times and I want it to return a different value the second time. – MvdD

You schould have written this in your question. The Solution is as simple as it sounds:

```
doReturn(VALUE_FOR_FIRST_CALL).
   thenReturn(VALUE_FOR_SECOND_CALL).
   thenReturn(VALUE_FOR_ANY_FURTHER_CALL).
   when(mock).theMethod();
```

Or if you prefer being less chatty:

```
doReturn(VALUE_FOR_FIRST_CALL, VALUE_FOR_SECOND_CALL, VALUE_FOR_ANY_FURTHER_CALL).
   when(mock).theMethod();
```

Comment: Instead of `new Answer` a Lambda would be more concise.

Comment: @A.H. Off cause I'd write a lambda too, but the *anonymous class* form is more descriptive for a newbee....

Comment: To be clear, my mock is returning a constant value. The mock is called multiple times and I want it to return a different value the second time.

Comment: Right, I was too focused on making the method argument determine the return value. This is the correct solution to my issue. BTW, what's the difference between using doReturn() and what I ended up writing: `when(dep.func(anyObject())).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going down the wrong rabbit hole. Meaning: mock specifications are *mock* specifications. They should not be *anything* else.

What I mean is: I would suggest that you write tests like:

```
@Test
public void testForTrue() {
    when(dep.func(any()).thenReturn(true);
    Sut sut = new Sut(dep);
    assertEquals(sut.method(new Arg(true)), "True");
}

@Test
public void testForFalse() {
    when(dep.func(any()).thenReturn(false);
    Sut sut = new Sut(dep);
    assertEquals(sut.method(new Arg(false)), "False");
}
```

If at all, I would then refactor to:

```
private void testFor(boolean depReturnValue, expectedResult) {
    when(dep.func(any()).thenReturn(depReturnValue);
    Sut sut = new Sut(dep);
    assertEquals(sut.method(new Arg(depReturnValue)), expectedResult);
}
```

and call that method from @Test methods as outlined above.

In other words: don't spend a lot of time and energy to have "intelligent" mocking specs. Rather focus on writing simple straight forward tests.

And when you can write a test *without* doing complicated analysis on the arguments passed to a mocked call - then go for that solution.

Comment: I may not have been completely clear with my example. The point is that the dependency is called multiple times and I want it to return different values each time. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: But still - at least according to your **usage** of `sut.method()` you are using the *same* argument for your assert. So dep.func() is invoked with the same object, and would thus return the same value all the time?

Comment: Yeah, again simplified example. In reality the argument to the next dependency call is generated internally inside `sut.method()` and depends on the return value of the first call.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. I was too focused on making the mock return something different depending on the argument passed in, since the mock method was called multiple times with a different complex argument object.

The solution was to just return a different result on subsequent invocations, which is simple using Mockito.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ArgumentMatcherTest {

    @Mock
    private Dependency dep = mock(Dependency.class);

    @Test
    public void test() {

        // return true on first invocation, false on second.
        when(dep.func(anyObject())).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);

        Sut sut = new Sut(dep);
        assertEquals(sut.method(new Arg(true)), "True");
        assertEquals(sut.method(new Arg(false)), "False");
    }
}
```